# Java library that adds/subtracts two Date objects to the precision of milliseconds

Tags: java, time, iso

I was looking thru java Date libraries
1. java.util.Date,
2. Date4J
3. Joda-time

to find out whether I can perform time subtraction to two Date Objects, to the precision of milliseconds.

I receive 2011-05-29T22:50:12.692 as a String, and convert it into a Date object by parsing it with SimpleDateFormat.

The other Date object will also be received a String. and I want to subtract from two Date objects.

Any ideas?

Basically i want to get an interval between the two Date objects, to the precision of milliseconds.

Comment: the standard date objects in java go to the level of milliseconds

Comment: Hi Sam Holder, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [Date.getTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

```
long timeBetweenInMillis = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
```

**EDIT**

This assumes that `d2` is **chronologically after** `d1`.

Comment: Hi mre, that gets me milliseconds. I am looking for an Date object, that has the precision of milliseconds, that is in ISO format (i.e. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS)

Comment: @Yakult121, isn't that what you asked for?...the interval between two Date objects, to the precision of milliseconds? that's exactly what the code I provided will do. using `Date.getTime()` returns the Date object with the precision of milliseconds. the formatting and parsing of your Date objects is entirely up to you.

Comment: I think he wants a Date object as the result.  I don't know why.  It will just be the number of milliseconds since epoch.  But to do that, just do  "Date result = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());"

Answer (score 2):

in java.util.Date there is a method called `Date.getTime()` that you can use to get the time in milies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
Date d1 = 
Date d2 =
long intervalInMillis = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
```

Comment: this will result in a negative amount of time between.

Comment: Hi mre, I've tried the code and i don't understand why there will be a negative amount of time between.
Wait. I got the subtraction backwards.

Comment: @Yakult121, read my edit. In this case, if `d2` occurs before `d1`, then `intervalInMillis` will be negative. if this is not the case, then `intervalInMillis` will not be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The internal representation of a Date() object is the number of milliseconds past the epoch.  Just get those values with the getTime() method and do arithmetic on them.  You can then construct a new Date object based on that value and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the millisecond difference:

```
long millis = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

Comment: this will result in a negative amount of time between.

Comment: @mre I guess that depends on which date is date1 and which is date2 :-)

Comment: yep...included an "explanation" in my answer. :)

Comment: @mre which is probably why you have more upvotes than the rest of us :-)

Comment: haha probably. And it's a shame because these are all correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage XMLGregorianCalendar instead of SimpleDateFormat (Note SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe:  http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html):

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2011-05-29T22:50:12.692");
        XMLGregorianCalendar date1 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2011-03-29T22:50:12.692");

        System.out.println(date2.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() - date1.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
    }

}
```

Comment: Not recommended.  This is using a data type for an unintended purpose.

Comment: @Tazzy531 - XMLGregorianCalendar is intended to Strings of that format to date information (part 1 of the problem).  SimpleDateFormat not being thread safe is important to note.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
Date result = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
```

**Explanation:**

```
d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()
```

Returns millisecond difference between the dates

```
new Date(milliseconds);
```

Creates a new Date object set to number of milliseconds since epoch.

**Edit**

IF you only want the positive difference, change it to this.  This way it doesn't matter what order you put in inputs:

```
Date result = new Date(Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()));
```